# AccuRev is ignoring my .acignore file

Tags: accurev

I have an .acignore file that looks like this:

```
**\build
**\build\**
**\.gradle
**\.gradle\**
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
AccuRev Workspaces
   .accurev
   Workspace1
   Workspace 2
```

I placed my .acignore file into the .accurev folder under AccuRev Workspaces and restarted AccuRev. It didn't start ignoring any of the files that I expected it to (and they are all external). I then put it directly under the AccuRev Workspaces folder and restarted; still no luck. I even put it in both of those places under an individual workspace and it didn't work. I'm at my wits' end. What is going on here????

Answer (score 0):

The .acignore file must be in the workspace top directory. In other words, you would need an .acignore in the Workspace1 directory and another in Workspace2. This allows you to have different ignore rules for each workspace. Alternatively, you could add it to source control if you have standard ignore rules applicable to all workspaces.